# Applying LDAP OU attributes to users automatically

Tags: active-directory, ldap, attributes

Is it possible to set the Office and Department attributes on an organizational unit, that way when we move users around, the user's office and department automatically changes?

I don't use AD/LDAP very much so I'm not sure if this is outside of the realm of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

An OU doesn't have those properties.

If you know PowerShell, you should be able to cook up and easy scrip to get all the users from an OU and add data for the 'office' and 'department' fields, it would take some testing to find out exactly what those fields are called though.

Hey, Scripting Guy! might even have something like this.